# Speeding up large file write to disk in c++

Tags: c++, performance, io, outputstream

I need to write a large csv file to disk.  I've reduced the problem to the below code.  When I compile with VS 2017 run on my Windows 7 box it runs on average in 26 seconds.  Could someone suggest a way to speed this up without changing the data container or output format?  Any help will be appreciated.

PS:Probably obvious, but the speedup should be to the base case on your hardware

I tried using fopen and fprintf but got worse results.  I also played around with setting the buffer size with no success.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream> 
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::vector<double> VecD;
typedef std::vector<VecD> VecVecD;

void test_file_write_stream() {
    VecVecD v(10000, VecD(2000, 1.23456789));
    const std::string delimiter(",");
    const std::string file_path("c:\\junk\\speedtest.csv");
    auto t1_stream = Clock::now();
    std::ofstream ostream(file_path.c_str());
    if (!ostream.good())
        return;
    ostream << std::setprecision(12);

    for (const auto & row : v) {
        for (const auto & col : row) {
            ostream << col << delimiter;
        }
        ostream << std::endl;
    }
    auto t2_stream = Clock::now();
    std::cout << "Stream test: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2_stream - t1_stream).count() / 1.0e6 << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

void main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    test_file_write_stream();
}
```

Stream test: 26.2086 seconds

Comment: 1) Did you compile your code with optimizations enabled (in VS: Release mode), before doing measurements? 2) If your code works correctly, and you are only interested in increasing performance: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be better place to ask such a question.

Comment: If you run the same program twice without _any_ pause between, do you get a very different result the second round?

Comment: Yes, the code is compiled in release mode.

Comment: Not significantly different.  There is variable load on the disk so I expect some minimal fluctuations.

Comment: Ok - Note: `void main()` should not compile using any compiler released this century.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  I just threw a test harness together.  VS2017 compiles it fine.

Comment: I'm surprised - I've used VS2017 and didn't find it that lacking. Turn on `/W4` warnings. It'll hopefully catch your chrono-cast followed by a division too. Why not use the correct chrono duration from start?

Comment: @stas "_VS2017 compiles it fine._" VS2017 throws `warning C4326: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'void'` when compiling. Always be compiling with `-W4`.

Comment: *When I compile with VS 2017 run on my Windows 7 box it runs on average in 26 seconds* -- You need to be careful.  If you try to optimize disk writes for your particular machine, you may slow down (or not even affect) speed on another machine.  You need to take in consideration a lot of factors.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - just a little qualification, in a hosted void `void main()` is wrong, in a freestanding environment, it can be valid as program startup is implementation defined.[What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)  `/W3` should be more than sufficient to catch the issues, `/W4`  brings in a lot of non-code MS specific warnings.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If the tags had mentioned such an environment, I wouldn't have mentioned it. It's now tagged `C++` and, no, `void main()` is not valid `C++`. If the link you shared says otherwise, it's outdated. `/W4` is usually good when you use what comes with the IDE. When bringing in other libraries you may need to relax it a bit - but I tend to stay at `/W4` for as long as I can.

Comment: Formatting (and also parsing) tens of millions of IEEE 754 doubles as decimal text is relatively expensive task. All standard libraries do it somewhat sub-optimally since text is anyway inferior media for that. If you badly need ... to squeeze all out of it then perhaps read that blog post https://www.zverovich.net/2019/02/11/formatting-floating-point-numbers.html

Comment: @ÖöTiib `std::format` looks nice. I haven't tried any of it yet. Can you try the prestanda compared to the original code and the raw dump? I guess it'll land somewhere inbetween, but one never knows.

Comment: Even if it is quicker compared to fprintf or ostream<< it is still doomed to be slower, less storage efficient and to have loss in precision compared to raw dump. Raw dump is limited with media speed (media write is taking about 10-40% of your program's run) and its media usage is also about 66% compared to text in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and made some minor hipshot-optimizations - but got consistant results. The baseline was ~14 s for me, and it stayed close to that all the time. Good work `-O3`.

I replaced your `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` with a one-dimensional version and `std::copy`ed it to disk with only a minor improvement.

Only when I gave up and dumped the memory as-is (**not** as a `.csv`) to disk did I get down to 1-3 seconds.

The big drawback is that what I dumped isn't portable in any way. It can hopefully be read back to the same computer on a good day, but I wouldn't recommend dumping `double`s this way for real:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

// custom 2D array with a 1D memory layout
template<typename T>
class array2d {
public:
    array2d(size_t h, size_t w, const T& value = T{}) : data_(h * w, value), w_(w) {}

    inline double* operator[](size_t y) { return &data_[y * w_]; }
    inline double const* operator[](size_t y) const { return &data_[y * w_]; }

    inline size_t width() const { return w_; }

    T const* data() const { return data_.data(); }
    size_t size() const { return data_.size(); }

private:
    std::vector<T> data_;
    size_t w_;
};

using VecVecD = array2d<double>;

void test_file_write_stream() {
    VecVecD v(10000, 2000, 1.23456789);

    const std::string delimiter(",");
    const std::string file_path("c:\\junk\\speedtest.csv");

    auto t1_stream = Clock::now();

    std::ofstream ostream(file_path.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    if(!ostream) return;

    ostream << std::setprecision(12);

    /* this may give a somewhat better performance than yours, but not much:

    std::copy(v.data(), v.data() + v.size(),
              std::ostream_iterator<double>(ostream, delimiter));
    */

    // non-portable binary dump
    ostream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data()),
                  static_cast<std::streamsize>(v.size() * sizeof(double)));

    auto t2_stream = Clock::now();

    auto elapsed_s =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t2_stream - t1_stream);
    std::cout << "Stream test: " << elapsed_s.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    test_file_write_stream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wan't to use is **memory mapped files** according to [wikipedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file):

> The benefit of memory mapping a file is increasing I/O performance,
>   **especially when used on large files**.

Why ? because the data is not needed to be *copied around an extra time* - and you should start seeing increases in the ballpark of 50%-100% or maybe more.

[boost](/questions/tagged/boost) has a very neat interface in [boost-interprocess](/questions/tagged/boost-interprocess). I do not have a testbench for this atm., but something ala:

```
boost::interprocess::file_mapping fm(filename, ...);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region region(fm, ...);
//mapped_region  is a memory mapped file
```

Otherwise, you can of course use the interface for your platform:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files